# Hybrid & Terrain mapTypeIds shadowed in mapTypeControl

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Starting to learn Google Maps, was playing a little with it when I crossed one little quirk I though I would share should anyone have an idea about its cause and solution.

Here's the thing : I try to show the **TERRAIN** and **HYBRID** map types on the map type's control, they show up fine when I only add them but once I add **SATELLITE** and **ROADMAP** types these last two take over, the first two will not be shown.

Here is the minimal code :

```
mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [
                google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                //google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                //google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            ]
        }
```

So if I un-comment the last two lines, the first two are as if not there!

Is that normal behavior ? Guess not, so what's wrong ? Any solution ?

Comment: Probably an isssue with your CSS.

Comment: @geocodezip : such as ?

Comment: What does your css look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything missing. When you click on a control you will see a dropdown with a checkbox(these checkboxes are the missing controls).

The TERRAIN-maptype shows TERRAIN-features only on a ROADMAP, while the HYBRID-maptype shows streets on a SATELLITE-view.

So HYBRID and TERRAIN only add additional features to the basic maptypes SATELLITE and ROADMAP, which may be chosen by the user via the checkboxes.

Comment: Meaning we can't display them all in the same time ?

Comment: Yes, but you may use custom controls

Comment: Excuse me but I feel the need to be hyper explicite about this : TERRAIN is like some super ROADMAP type, HYBRID is like some SATELLITE type, you don't show all and you can only have (TERRAIN, SATELLITE), (TERRAIN, HYBRID), (ROADMAP, SATELLITE) or (ROADMAP, HYBRID) pairs, is that it ? If this so, since when ? Cause I can still find example where the map type control shows four choices at once...

Comment: Well the example I found is on the "beginning google maps api 3" book of Svennerberg. Check page 69.

Comment: this is a picture in a  3 years old book, not an example

Comment: Yes, still. So I guess I should rely more on the developers site of google then. Thanks anyways.